# Get custom post type label instead of name - WordPress + Timber

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I created 3 custom post types in WordPress : `dissertation`, `subject-imposed`, `subject-free`

In each custom post type the user is allowed to create only ONE post.

I created a menu composed with those three custom post types which allow to switch from post to another from the same user.

But I got a problem. The menu item display the name of the post type and not the label.

I got : DISSERTATION / SUBJECT-IMPOSED / SUBJECT FREE

And I would like the label (labels are in french) : MEMOIRE / SUJET IMPOSE / SUJET LIBRE

How can I get the label instead ? Thank you in advance.

**In single.php :**

```
$post_queried = get_queried_object();
$context['post_type_current'] = get_post_type_object(get_post_type($post_queried));

$get_post_current_user = get_posts( array(
    'author' => $current_user->ID,
    'post_type' => array('dissertation', 'subject-imposed', 'subject-free'),
));

$context['list_posts_current_user'] = $get_post_current_user;
```

**In single.twig :**

```
<ul class="menu-secondary__list">
    {% for item in list_posts_current_user %}
        {% set active = (post_type_current.name == item.post_type) ? 'active' : '' %}
        <li class="menu-secondary__item"><a href="{{ item.guid }}" class="menu-secondary__link h-item {{ active }}">{{ item.post_type }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps to fix this one, first ...

### Convert into an array of Timber\Posts

`$get_post_current_user` is an array of `WP_Post`s we need to convert these to `Timber\Post`s in order to interact with Timber's methods. Many ways to do this, but the easiest ...

`{% for item in Post(list_posts_current_user) %}`

### Access the type method:

Now you can use the `Post::type()` method in your Twig template and access the labels:

`{{ item.type.labels.name }}`

The `{{ item.type }}` property will give you everything from here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_object/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. When I do a print_r of item.type : {{ item.type|print_r }} in my loop is empty

Comment: Ahhhhh! You are right. I missed a step. See the updated answer!

Comment: Ohh thank you very much for your update. I changed get_posts by Timber::get_posts. It work perfectly ! Thank you again

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to give an order of the item of my menu : DISSERTATION / SUBJECT-IMPOSED / SUBJECT FREE for the moment I got : SUBJECT-IMPOSED / DISSERTATION / SUBJECT FREE